# how to return two dataframes inside a user function

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, group-by

My purpose is to create a function like:

```
def function(x):
    mask_1 = (x["var_1"] == 0) & (x["var_2"] == 0) 
    df_1 = x[mask_1]
    df_1 = x[['A','B']].groupby(['A']).count().reset_index()
    df_1.rename(columns={'B':'my_fan_type_1'}, inplace=True)
    mask_2 = (x["var_1"] == 0) & (x["var_2"] == 1)
    df_2 = x[['A','B']].groupby(['A']).count().reset_index()
    df_2.rename(columns={'B':'my_fan_type_2'}, inplace=True)
    return df_1, df_2


df_1,df_2 = df_to_be_filtered.apply(function, axis=1)
```

In a nutshell, I have a dataframe and I want to create a function that first filter some rows then create two dataframes based on those rows, grouping by and counting.
the dataframe to be filtered is the same to the two cases. If I create this function I don't get the expected result.

Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: what do you get ? And what did you expect ? Maybe your problem is in your calculations. Use `print()` in function to see what you have in different moments in variables.

Comment: why do you use `df_attive_pm` in function if you didn't create it? Maybe it should be `df_1` instead of `df_attive_pm`

Comment: Besides df_attive_pm @furas mentioned, your masks are actually not used. Your df1 and df2 will be identical except for the column name. Are you trying to take different masks and output summary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your code to work, the masks should be applied to the dataframe first. then operate on the filtered dataframe.

```
def function(x):
    # construct df_1
    mask_1 = (x["var_1"] == 0) & (x["var_2"] == 0) 
    df_1 = x[mask_1][['A','B']].groupby(['A']).count().reset_index()
    df_1.rename(columns={'B':'my_fan_type_1'}, inplace=True)

    # construct df_2
    mask_2 = (x["var_1"] == 0) & (x["var_2"] == 1)
    df_2 = x[mask_2][['A','B']].groupby(['A']).count().reset_index()
    df_2.rename(columns={'B':'my_fan_type_2'}, inplace=True)

    return df_1, df_2

df_1,df_2 = function(df)
```

The above code is doing minimum change on the original one, constructing df1 and df2 separately and return both.

Comment: in answer you should describe what you do in code. You could add text from comment as description for your code.